# How do you remove shell integration from VisualStudio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am on MacOS.  I use `zsh` + `oh-my-zsh` + `starship`.

The VisualStudio code shell integration scripts have taken over completely and I fear are on the verge of destroying the human race.

In my iTerm2 this is an example of what my prompt looks like:
[image: The prompt I want]

In the VSCode Terminal this is my prompt:

[image: The prompt I get]

In my VSCode settings I have the following set

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false,
"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.decorationsEnabled": "never",
```

I even found the shell integration scripts and commented them out completely, yet the prompt never returns back to what I want it to be.

How do I completely and forever disable the VSCode shell prompt injection?

Comment: what makes you think that this behaviour is due to shell integration and not just with sourcing of prompt config scripts?

Comment: Because I've found the shell integration scripts where it wants to rewrite $PS1 and $PS2.  I've commented them out of those scripts, yet it still re-writes the prompt lines.

Comment: 1) and those scripts change the value of $PS1 such that what you're seeing which you don't want is the result of the change? 2) Where is the script that sets $PS1 to what you _want_ it to be? How is that script sourced in the startup files of your shell? Are you sure that that script / line of that script is being run in the VS Code terminal profile of interest?